# Rotation matrix defined by radial coordinate system's $\theta$ and $\phi$

Tags: transformation, coordinate-systems, rotations

Lets consider a regular Cartesian coordinate system $A$. From its origin, I draw a unit vector, defined by the radial $\theta$ (tilt from $z$-axis) and $\phi$ ( angle between the $x$-axis and the vectors projection on the $xy$ plane).

I would like to define a new plane $S$, that is perpendicular to that vector, and a new coordinate system $A'$ in which the $x'$ and $y'$ axes are parallel to the plane. One more freedom degree is kept, a "rotation" of the $x'y'$ axes in respect to the $z'$ axis. For now, let's define this angle as 0.

I am looking for a transformation $R(\theta,\phi)$ so that:
$$(x,y,z)=R(x',y',z')$$

Comment: You’ve got two rotations. Compose them.

Comment: this does't work because these angles ($\theta , \phi $) are not defined as rotations around an axis.
or am I missing something?

Comment: The first is a rotation about the $x$-axis, the second about the $z$-axis.

Comment: this could work if i would be able to make the second rotation around the original $z$-axis, but that axis was moved after the first rotation.

Comment: Don’t think of it that way. Imagine starting with the unit vector $(0,0,1)^T$ and rotating it into position using the given angles. If that doesn’t work for you, look up spherical coordinates and see how they relate to rotations.